# Is there any way I can control the output of my webcam?

Tags: linux, video, webcam, video-streaming, linux-terminal

I actually got this idea when I was using Google Hangouts; I was wondering if there was any way I could "hack" my webcam to make Hangouts display video that wasnt actually being supplied as input.

I'm not necessarily looking for a tool to do this for me, more just whether there was command-line magic that I could use to make this work. Maybe something like

```
webcam -override loopingvideo.mp4
```

Comment: Not sure about Linux, but on Windows there is [ManyCam](http://manycam.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could use v4l2loopback to create a loopback device as, say, /dev/video1 and then use mplayer on the command line to push your mp4 to the new loopback device, then just point your hangout's webcam settings to /dev/video1 instead of /dev/video0 (assuming your current device is /dev/video0).

Chances are that you will have to fiddle around to make v4l2loopback happy with the video format you are sending to it, but that's par for the course on a linux box.